# Bootstrap Dropdown not working using Pingendo

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I know this question has been dealt with in multiple threads, but I am still banging my head against the wall.

I cannot get my nav bars to work using bootstrap. In fact it seems to me that most of the nav bars on Bootstraps demopage don't work either. Or maybe they are meant to be in a permanently open state for learning purposes.

Either way I cannot get any nav bar on [www.dknytkom.dk/artikel.html](http://www.dknytkom.dk/artikel.html) to work.

On Bootstrap demo page [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar](https://dknytkom/KomBoot/artikel.html) it sems to me that the class ".open" is applied to the surrounding div. But this is not happening on my site. This class come from an external bootstrap less file.

I am marking up my pages in a Bootstrap wysiwyg-editor (Pingendo) that uses SASS. It should automatically make use of all bootstrap JS capabilities but maybe there is a conflict of some sort. It doesn't matter whether I use the built-in nav bar or if I copy-paste the one from the BS demopages.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

So I omitted the Pingendo Bootstrap JS (src="https://pingendo.com/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6.min.js">) and opted for the Bootstrap CDN at Maxcdn and also included the Bootstrap.minified at Cloudfare and alas it worked.

I will direct this questions to the gyus at Pingendo.